# Fault on @ symbol in XML file

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, soa, mds

I am trying to import a file having the symbol `@` into Weblogic server MDS. While importing, looks like the parser is not able to parse `@`, and throws an error.

Is there any escape character (like `&amp;` for `&`), using which I can make use of the symbol `@` in XML?

Comment: What is the error thrown? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

`@` can appear as any other character in an XML file; it is not like, say `&` that must be presented as `&amp;`, for example, when not used to introduce an entity name.

It is possible that you've placed it somewhere it's not allowed.  For example, it cannot be used in an element name.